# Access dynamic object by name in a loop

Tags: c#, loops

I am new to c# as am a php / js / html developer.
I have 8 switches named relay_1,relay_2,relay_3 etc etc
I need to be able to change the state of these but I would like to do through a for loop so the number is dynamic.
I have tried various methods but to no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is what I would like ( not correct )

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  relay_" + i.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Comment: You don't want to do this, you want to learn about collection types.  Trust me, every beginner thinks they want this, but it's only because they don't understand collections (arrays, lists, etc.)

Comment: forget php, js and html. C# is a strongly typed (serious) language. You need to learn about OOP and as mentioned above you're looking for a List or Collection.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot generate the name of a variable dynamically, but you can create an array of `relay` objects (the `allRelays` variable below), and do your operation in a loop, like this:

```
var allRelays = new {relay_0, relay_1, relay_2, relay_3, relay_4, relay_5, relay_6, relay_7, relay_8};
foreach (var relay in allRelays) {
    relay.IsChecked = true;
}
```